# Wordpress: how to get events from the default audio player?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, audio

I'm currently using Wordpress 4.0 and all my audios on posts/pages are embedded using the default Wordpress audio player - through a shortcode like:

`[audio http://en.support.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/mattmullenweg-interview.m4a]`

Now, I want to track how many times the play button is pressed. So, my question is: **how can I capture this player events?**

**PS:** I tried the following (and it didn't work):

```
$('.mejs-playpause-button button').click(function(){
    console.log('TESTING');
});
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it'll make any difference but try doing the following ```$('.mejs-playpause-button').on('click', 'button', function(){
    console.log('TESTING');
});```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the event propogation for that button is being prevented by the MediaElementJS library that manages the audio element.

As an alternative I would suggest listening for 'play' events on either the MediaElementJS element or directly selecting the native HTML audio element and listening for the 'play' event on this object.

I briefly attempted to get the MediaElementJS instance for a player but it is hard to get hold off because of the way that [Wordpress makes these instances](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0-branch/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.js).

However you can add an event listener to an audio element and record the amount of times this element is fired:

```
  $('audio').on('play', function(){                           
        console.log("play");                                                  
   });
```

This might not be the best solution if you have multiple elements on a page though.